# Bootstrap 3 responsive columns of varying heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

**EDIT** The pricing tables' content will all be dynamically generated, I cannot predict their height, I'm simply using the **400px** case for the diagram. So I can't set a static height to each column as a fix.

I have 8 pricing tables
They are all **similar** heights close to 400px, with the **largest (red square)** being 430px and the smallest at a height of 390px.

Responsive class for columns: `class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"`

HTML layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <% columns.each do |column| %>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    <% end %>   
</div>
```

How do I prevent columns being pushed off into **"new row"**, i.e.
All the columns are contained in the same `div.row` tag so they can act responsively.
But in the second set of columns, the first two "slots" are skipped, the third row (not shown) begins like normal however.

**IMPORTANT THAT THEY'RE ALL IN THE SAME `.row` OBJECT**
So that responsive aspect works and columns collapse down.

### Diagram of problem:

[image: column_problem]

### What I want is something more like this:

[image]

Comment: after 3 cols for md, 2 for sm, 4 for lg, you can add a div with style "clear:both".

Comment: Use clearfix divs like in this example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: @Pietro This was the right answer, can you please post it as an answer so I can give you credit?
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after 3 cols for md, 2 for sm, 4 for lg, you can add a div with style "clear:both" using mod (%).

Comment: Add some code please! I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can be clever with media queries, and clear the first item in the next row depending on the resolution size.

```css
.regular {
    background: gray;
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.tall {
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .fix-row > div:nth-child(3) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .fix-row > div:nth-child(3) {
        clear: none;
    }
    .fix-row > div:nth-child(4) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    .fix-row > div:nth-child(3) {
        clear: none;
    }
    .fix-row > div:nth-child(4) {
        clear: none;
    }
    .fix-row > div:nth-child(5) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row fix-row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="regular">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="tall">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="regular">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="regular">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="regular">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="regular">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="regular">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="regular">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="regular">
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tkL8edwj/

**How it Works:**

I'm using media queries to determine when the last row item is, then using the CSS pseudo selector `nth-child(n)` to specify the last item in the row.

Since you are using `col-lg-3`, `col-md-4`, and `col-md-6` for your grid item classes, I can know the first item in the next row based on the default Bootstap break points.

`col-lg-4` breaks at a certain point (1200px), and because you are using `4` I know there are 3 items in the row (12/4 = 3).  That means I can target every **5th** div in the row and get the first item of each row, and then use `clear: left` to ensure it clears the float of the divs before it.

Same thing for the rest of the break-points.  I'll notice I'm also resetting the `clear` to `clear: none` when necessary so the one's previously targets don't break at the wrong resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use CSS column-width like this..

```
.row {
 -moz-column-width: 20em;
 -webkit-column-width: 20em;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;
 -webkit-column-gap:10px; 
}

.row > .col-lg-3 {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 100%; 
 float:none;
}
```

**Demo:** http://bootply.com/jFdfbBgkv6

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you're talking about as I have ran into the same issue. I don't know ruby, but the answer is simple:

1. Use a `for` loop with a counter `i`
2. When `i % 4 == 0`, print: `<%= </div><div class="row"> %>` after your `<div class='col'>`.

This way, every 4 entries, the `class='row'` will stop and create a new one. and the last row will not affect the next row and the `class='col'` will not be affected. This also works when screen size is lowered.

Comment: Wouldn't this break when the responsiveness kicks in and you then have 3 columns in a large viewport, and 6 columns in a small viewport?