# How to make each div the same height, in order to keep the 3 div per row alignment working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alignment, height

My site contains a series of divs (represented by green boxes), and I only need 3 per row. But they're not all equal height, so it pushes the other divs out of alignment.

**See here:**

[image: Screenshot]

and here's my demo site showing the full issue if you scroll down:   http://testsite24.netai.net/public/demo.html

Here's an example of the code for one of the divs (green boxes):

```
<div class="block personal fl">

                <!-- CONTENT -->
               <div class="content">
                  <p class="price">
                    <p class="vignette" style="background-image:url()"></p>
                  </p>

               </div>

                <ul class="features">
    <li class="titlebox">59 Acre Paradise</li>
    <li>Kings County</li>
    <li>Offered at $95,000</li>
                  </ul>

</div>
```

Can you offer a solution to make all div heights the same height, so they stay in alignment? The solution must work for IE8+. Perhaps a script to identify the longest div in the row and make the other two the same height?

Previously I used this script, but FlexWrap isn't supported by IE8/IE9 so I had to scrap it. Any ideas? Thank you!!

```
<script>

;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
{
    'use strict';

    var s = document.body || document.documentElement, s = s.style;
    if( s.webkitFlexWrap == '' || s.msFlexWrap == '' || s.flexWrap == '' ) return true;

    var $list       = $( '.list' ),
        $items      = $list.find( '.list__item__inner' ),
        setHeights  = function()
        {
            $items.css( 'height', 'auto' );

            var perRow = Math.floor( $list.width() / $items.width() );
            if( perRow == null || perRow < 2 ) return true;

            for( var i = 0, j = $items.length; i < j; i += perRow )
            {
                var maxHeight   = 0,
                    $row        = $items.slice( i, i + perRow );

                $row.each( function()
                {
                    var itemHeight = parseInt( $( this ).outerHeight() );
                    if ( itemHeight > maxHeight ) maxHeight = itemHeight;
                });
                $row.css( 'height', maxHeight );
            }
        };

    setHeights();
    $( window ).on( 'resize', setHeights );
    $list.find( 'img' ).on( 'load', setHeights );

})( jQuery, window, document );

</script>
```

Comment: Why not use css instead of javascript

Comment: Try: http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/equal-heights/

Comment: Someone asked this question [before][1]. They received a couple of answers.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119377/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-varying-heights/28119957#28119957

Comment: Appreciate it, but their example seems to allow for different height divs, as long as alignment isn't compromised. I'm looking for same height divs for each row.

Answer (score 1):

This seems super excessive when you can just use `vertical-align:top;` on the items... Give them a min-height to make it a bit stronger.

Comment: Thanks Shan, can you be specific as to which css item I attach this to? Does it apply to the div class "block personal fl" ?  I used Inspect Element, and changed it to .block {
width: 30%;
margin: 0 15px;
vertical-align: top;
margin-bottom: 30px;
max-height: 10%;
min-height: 10%;
overflow: hidden;

But can't see a change.

Comment: Ya, give that block vertical-align & `display:inline-block` it won't work with block elements FYI. How are you laying those boxes out? Floating? fixed with? Percentage?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of my page, after implementing your changes. You can see I'm using float:left; it looks.   The changes don't seem to work though:  http://testsite24.netai.net/public/screenshot3.png

Answer (score 1):

use

```
display: table
display: table-cell
```

Code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mypGBV

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, here's the screenshot:

http://testsite24.netai.net/public/screenshot2.png

Comment: What's not working? The divs are height aligned as requested, and there are 3 columns.

Comment: I don't see any green boxes whatsoever. Am I misunderstanding something? I want green boxes like this: http://testsite24.netai.net/public/screenshot4.png  except even heights. Your example is just white space with text as a result.

Comment: Changed it to be as simple as possible with green boxes. Hopefully it works now

Comment: Seems to work Kira thank you, except that I need exactly three boxes per row. The following link shows a demo with 4 boxes, with the 4th on the same row. Instead I need the 4th box to be positioned under the 1st.  And if I add a box (div) between boxes 1 and 2, it should push 2 over into 3's position, and 3 down into the new row. Ideas??

http://testsite24.netai.net/public/demo4.html

Comment: Add another row div with the three more items. Ive update the code pen to reflect what I mean. This wont solve the problem of wanting to be able to just add another div and have it slide down. It's too tied to having a parent "row" so everytime you want to insert a box you will have to "shift" everything over. Depending on how often you do that or what your requirements are this might not be preferable, or you might be able to get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **max-height** to force the div(which is causing trouble) not to get bigger than the particular value. For Example set all 3 divs to max-height:50px. They won't get bigger and remain aligned.

Comment: I've added a max-height of 600px, and there still is a white space. Here's a screenshot:   http://testsite24.netai.net/public/screenshot4.png

Comment: Actually max-height does not set the current height. It just tells browser not to exceed this limit.

Comment: So, it's not the solution I'm looking for?  I simply want all green boxes to be equal height, with responsive height based on the content of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS for this. Just wrap each row of divs in a wrapper div with the style `clear: both` set. See this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgyXNp

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the divs are *not* equal height when I view your codepen