# Remove gap between floated element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have some floated `div` with variable height but same width.
Some times there is a vertical gap between tow `divs`, how can I prevent this?
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ss6pq2L0/2/

Comment: Code always goes in your question first. Also the BS graid is based on 12 columns. Yours totals 42.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put it in 2 columns? Other than that I don't think there is a solution to this.

Comment: @jo8691 not necessarily, he is just defining the width of each div and as expected if a div doesn't fit it will drop down. For example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping

Comment: @joshhunt No necessarily what?

Comment: You said "Also the BS graid is based on 12 columns. Yours totals 42", but this isn't correct, his is still based on 12 columns it just pushes the next columns down.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is the "grid" and is to be expected. A row is going to have a fixed height across all columns. When the cell in the first column is higher, two (or more) will float on top of each other in the second column.

If you are OK with the div's being ordered vertically in columns, you can get rid of those gaps like this. (Pardon the inline style.)

```
<div class="row" style="column-count:2">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div style="height: 80px"></div>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Adding this CSS will help keep the columns from breaking in the middle of the item (in modern browsers).

```
.col-xs-12 { 

  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will split some divs into two so it might not be an ideal solution, see: https://jsfiddle.net/75gjs30r/ (not saying this answer is wrong, just depends on his situation)

Comment: thanks, but I want to  divs being ordered horizontally not vertically.

Comment: and @joshhunt is right I don't want divs to be splited.

Comment: Are you looking for something more like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119377/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-varying-heights

Comment: If you want them ordered horizontally I don't believe this is possible using Boostrap grids (or any way using just css). If you have a look at Pinterest (which is how I think you want it) they use Javascript to set absolute positions.